# Why does the small and large loaded neural nets take the same amount of RAM?

Tags: c++, neural-network, caffe, conv-neural-network

At the beginning, I have trained one convolutional neural network in *caffe* framework, whose model weighed 80Mb. Although, I have noticed that after the loading it in to my project, it takes almost 1 Gb of RAM. On the internet I have found out that any CNN takes a lot of memory. That is why I thought that smaller CNN would solve my problem. I trained another one with less layers in it. In the end, the model weighted only 60Mb but still took the previous 1Gb of RAM memory.

Before you answer my question, please be aware that:

1) When I was measuring the amount of taken memory, I have commented every line of my project and the only thing remaining was the loaded model.

2) I have checked the amount of memory taken using the terminal command 'htop' (yes they are equal)

P.S. I am new to DNN, is there any other solution? Thank you for your help!

**UPDATE**

I have created the net with one hidden layer (Just for the sake of experiment) and loaded it into my project. Taking to the account, that the model weights only 160Kb and still takes 1Gb of RAM memory, I certainly do not understand how to load the caffe model into the project. I am using the caffe library and load the model with the class 'classifier'. Again, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Obviosly, the size your process takes in the RAM doesn't depend on the size of the net. There must be something else. If you are interested what exactly - there are memory profiling tools, that can report where the memory is gone.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Yeah, I have understood that. As I said I have commented all the lines except the "Classifier classifier(model_file, trained_file, mean_file, label_file);" These class takes my RAM. Do you have any idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Use a memory profiling tool. It would show you what takes the memory, but probably require you to build caffe from source.

Comment: Oh, sorry I did not get your first answer. I forgot about the profiling tools. I will try it and write the output. Once again, thank you!